# Install another php version

Tags: php, symfony, redhat

Currently, I have **PHP 5.2.11**. We have a new project to be deployed which uses Symfony Framework and uses a higher php version. We can't upgrade to a newer version since there are a lot of running application which uses the lower version. So in this case, I need to install another PHP version for it to run. I already searched for some tutorials yet I ended up confused. I would really appreciate your help with this. I'm using **Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4** by the way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can install any version of PHP, and maintain multiple installs in different directories.  See the configure option `--prefix` to determine where it will be installed to during compiling PHP.  You don't need to use RPMs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily install multiple versions of php. The problem is that it's difficult to associate multiple php versions to web server simultaneously. For testing purpose you can use built in web server of php.

1) Download php source from http://php.net/downloads.php

2) tar -xvf php-5*

3) cd php-5* && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/bin/php && make && make install

4) /usr/local/bin/php -v

5) cd your_symfony project

6) /usr/local/bin/php -S ip:8080

7) Take ip:8080 in browser.

Comment: By the way, I have a question.. which directory shall I place my Symfony project @Harikrishnan?

Comment: You can place it any directory. Probably /var/www/html

Comment: One more thing, do I still need to configure something in the `httpd.conf`? Like setting the document root and the likes.. thanks for the response.

Comment: No configuration needed. As I mentioned , there is nothing to do with apache.